# Fill the Treeview from CombO

Tags: vb.net

I have 5 ComboBox. Each has an unlimited number of elements, and some are empty. What I want is to add the name ComboBox to the Treeview as "Parent". And List items in the ComboBox as "childern" in "Parent". . If the ComboBox is empty, it Is being ignored.

I want a code that works on FrameWork 3

MY CODE

MY CODE

```
  Public Sub TREEVIEWFILL()
        TreeView1.Nodes.Clear()

        If Com_A.SelectedIndex > -1 Then
            TreeView1.Nodes.Add(Com_A.Text, Com_A.Text)
            For i = 0 To Com_A.Items.Count - 1

                TreeView1.Nodes.Add(Com_A.Text, Com_A.Items(i).ToString)
            Next
        End If

        If Com_B.SelectedIndex > -1 Then
            TreeView1.Nodes(Com_A.Text).Nodes.Add(Com_B.Text, Com_B.Text)
            For i = 0 To Com_B.Items.Count - 1

                TreeView1.Nodes(Com_A.Text).Nodes.Add(Com_B.Text, Com_B.Items(i).ToString)
            Next

        End If

        If Com_C.SelectedIndex > -1 Then
            TreeView1.Nodes(Com_A.Text).Nodes(Com_B.Text).Nodes.Add(Com_C.Text, Com_C.Text)
            For i = 0 To Com_C.Items.Count - 1
                TreeView1.Nodes(Com_A.Text).Nodes(Com_B.Text).Nodes.Add(Com_C.Text, Com_C.Items(i).ToString)
            Next

        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Now which one is the desired tree? The one that you describe or what your code indicates. Please elaborate which is the parent of which. An image would help to clarify what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi dr.null name ComboBox to the Treeview as "Parent". And List items in the ComboBox as "childern" in "Parent"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your comment, you can do for example:

```vb
' +
Imports System.Linq

Public Sub TREEVIEWFILL()
    Dim cboxes = {Com_A, Com_B, Com_C, Com_D, Com_F}

    TreeView1.BeginUpdate()
    TreeView1.Nodes.Clear()

    For Each cmb In cboxes.Where(Function(x) x.Items.Count > 0)
        Dim node As New TreeNode(cmb.Name,
                                    cmb.Items.Cast(Of String).
                                    Select(Function(x) New TreeNode(x)).ToArray())

        TreeView1.Nodes.Add(node)
    Next

    TreeView1.EndUpdate()
End Sub
```

Or without using `LINQ`:

```vb
Public Sub TREEVIEWFILL()
    Dim cboxes = {Com_A, Com_B, Com_C, Com_D, Com_F}

    TreeView1.BeginUpdate()
    TreeView1.Nodes.Clear()

    For Each cmb In cboxes
        If cmb.Items.Count > 0 Then
            Dim parent As New TreeNode(cmb.Name)

            For Each item As String In cmb.Items
                parent.Nodes.Add(item, item)
            Next

            TreeView1.Nodes.Add(parent)
        End If
    Next

    TreeView1.EndUpdate()
End Sub
```

Note, you should call the `.BeginUpdate()` and `.EndUpdate()` methods when you call the `.Nodes.Add(..)` method to populate the tree.

Comment: When I reuse and fill in the Treeview, when I use another element, it does not delete the branches and remains saved

Comment: I do not know the reason

Comment: @monemahmed You are welcome. How? As you can see in the code, the entire tree is cleared by calling the `TreeView1.Nodes.Clear()` method. So, when you change the combo boxes' contents and repopulate the tree by recalling the `TREEVIEWFILL()` method, everything will be cleared and the updated contents will be populated. Maybe you need something else I haven't got it yet. Just try to explain what you need and I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Yes, I reformat the code and forgot to delete. Sorry for the mistake on my part.